# Visual Studio 10 - How can I start an application several times in the same project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

I want to start an application several times in Visual Studio. I have a solution which contains 2 projects, for example Client and Server. I select Server porject as a startup
and debug it. After this I want to select client as a startup and debug (or start) it several times. In this scenario I need to start Client project several times for multiple connection.

So, my question is how can I start an appliction several times in the same project?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any particular project, you can right-click on it in Solution Explorer and choose Debug-> Start new Instance, to launch a new copy of it, if that's what you're asking.

This is completely independent from which project(s) are marked as startup projects.